# MySQL check the existence of the data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really new to SQL, and have a question relate to check the existence of the data

I have several table, Table_A, Table_B1, Table_B2, Table_B3, ... , Table_Bn, in the following format:

Table_A

```
id | Name | Value 
-- |  --  | -- 
01 | Alex | xx
02 | Ben  | xx
03 | Jack | xx
... 
99 | Ken  | xx
```

Table_B1

```
id
--
05
18
...
79
```

Table_B2

```
id
--
18
...
84
```

etc.

What I hope to get is a table kind of like this：

```
id | Name | B1exist | B2exist | ... | Bnexist
-- | ---- | ------- | ------- | --- | -------  
05 |      |    1    |    0    |     |        
18 |      |    1    |    1    |     |        
22 |      |    0    |    0    |     |        
... 
79 |      |    1    |    0    |     |        
84 |      |    0    |    1    |     |
```

i.e., summarizing distinct id occur in B1，B2, ... ，Bn，see if each of them exist in each B table

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried that isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Select Table_A.id, Table_A.name, (...) IFNULL(B1_1.num, 0) as B1exists, IFNULL(B2_1.num, 0) as B2exists, ....., IFNULL(BN_1.num, 0) as BNexists
From Table_A
Left join (Select id, 1 as num From Table_B1) as B1_1 on Table_A.id = B1_1.id
Left join (Select id, 1 as num From Table_B2) as B2_1 on Table_A.id = B2_1.id
...
Left join (Select id, 1 as num From Table_BN) as BN_1 on Table_A.id = BN_1.id
```

Comment: Thanks! It also works well. Although it takes me quite a long time to understand the whole thing, but helped me learn a lot SQL grammer. Thanks again!

Comment: And it is easier to deal with when a new 'B' table is being added.

Comment: Happy to help! I used subqueries because the Bx tables only had one column ('id'), and the subquery adds a new column where every value is 1 (1 as num). The subquery can be referenced as a normal table if you name it (as Bx_1). Then it left joins all your Bx_1 tables to your A table, meaning if you have a value ('id' in this case) in your left (A) table, but not your right (Bx_1), the Bx_1 will be NULL for that row. Then the IFNULL statement swaps that NULL into a '0'. If you have the same 'id' in Bx_1, then you will have a '1' and IFNULL ignores it. Hope that helps in the understanding.

Comment: Also, don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Oh thanks for reminding me that! It my first time to ask a question here, and I just realized I should click the '√' to accept an answer if it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is a massive `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id, max(isb1), max(isb2), max(isb3)
from ((select id, 0 as isb1, 0 as isb2, 0 as isb3 from ids
      ) union all
      (select id, 1 as isb1, 0 as isb2, 0 as isb3 from b1
      ) union all
      (select id, 0 as isb1, 1 as isb2, 0 as isb3 from b2
      ) union all
      (select id, 0 as isb1, 0 as isb2, 1 as isb3 from b3
      )
     ) i
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very straightforward and easy to understand for beginners like me. It indeed works, especially for the case that 'n' is not very large.